Belassen/Verlassen confusion
Would you agree that they kind of made a mistake in this article, i.e. that they contradict themselves?
First they say

"dass Israel vor der Wahl stehe: Truppen in der Philadelphi-Passage zu belassen oder die Geiseln zurückzugeben",

but then a guy is quoted as saying that the Wahl Israel is facing consists of

"entweder Philadelphia zu verlassen oder die Geiseln zurückzubringen".

https://freedert.online/der-nahe-osten/217520-netanjahu-betrachtet-befreiung-der-geiseln-nicht-als-israelische-prioritaet/

Yeah, they confused it a lot. Those sentences must read

… , dass Israel vor der Wahl stehe, Truppen in der Philadelphi-Passage zu belassen oder die Geiseln zurückzulassen.
… , entweder Philadelphia zu verlassen oder die Geiseln zu befreien.

The original sentences have been translated from English too literally. I think the Israelis did it themselves. One of the IDF press officers who's been on German media speaks German like a native speaker. Almost. That's the kind of mistake that would slip through. (Actually, I think he's a native speaker but doesn't speak enough German to iron those things out.)

I don't think "befreien" is the original meaning, because it is a hypothetical quote of a Hamas leader, who would never acknowledge the possibility of freeing the hostages using troops.

The contradiction is already present in the "The Times of Israel" article your linked article is based on (https://www.timesofisrael.com/asked-to-decide-between-hostages-or-philadelphi-netanyahu-said-to-prefer-latter/):

two possibilities — either keeping the IDF deployed on the Philadelphi Corridor or bringing home the hostages

vs

If Sinwar presents you with the dilemma: Either you leave Philadelphi or you return the hostages, what do you do?

I think the second version is wrong. "Return" sounds a bit strange anyway, maybe the correct translation (from Hebrew) would have been something like "abandon".
